# Laravel 4.2 br tags to nl in textarea makes double tags

Tags: php, laravel, textarea, nl2br

so i have this problem with Laravel 4.2, that i have a textarea for updating the user profiles "about me", if i take it down from the database it works fine, i tried to do nl2br and hide the br tags, sort of worked aswell, problem is, when i write from scratch and make text like:

```
"hello

welcome to my profile"
```

it looks fine on the page it's extracted to, however, if i enter my profile editing page again, it will display with twice the space as such:

```
"hello



welcome to my profile"
```

i'm not exactly sure how to fix this, but hoping someone else may know.

my laravel code for extracting it at the moment is this:

```
{{ Form::textarea('about_me', $user->about_me = str_replace("<br />", "\n", $user->about_me), array('class' => 'profile-input')) }}
```

thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: Try get $user->about_me first, after that import value to Form:textarea

Comment: could you try and give me an example? i just tried and i just get errors, so i'm not entirely sure how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
{{ Form::textarea('about_me', nl2br(e($user->about_me)), array('class' => 'profile-input')) }}
```

Hope it help.

Comment: i tried, and deleted the ) after $user->about_me as it ended the text area, and i get the following error:

Comment: Illegal string offset 'name'

Comment: ah no worries, i found a fix, it's me being stupid, so i saved to database where it converted nl2br, and then when taking it back to the regular view page it was fine, but messed up in the editing page because it doubled the tags, so i changed that so it's raw data in database now, and then when i drag it down, it works on the editing page, and realised i needed to do nl2br on the profile page where the text is displayed, but thanks anyways, and the e tag helped me too with fixing people that could mess up a site by typing tags, so it wasn't all for naught :)

Comment: You're welcome! Try little more each day make everyone grow.