# Saving <br /> tags twice when editing data in form Laravel {!! (nl2br(e)) !!}

Tags: php, laravel, edit, line-breaks

I'm having a problem editing data after saving it with line breaks. When I'm saving data into the database, I display the data using {!! nl2br(e($data)) !!} . This works fine and it's not showing the 
 tags in the view. But when I'm trying to edit the data again the 
 tags show up in the edit form. Probably because I'm saving the tags twice. How would I solve this?

This question has the same problem: [Laravel 4.2 br tags to nl in textarea makes double tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41237956/laravel-4-2-br-tags-to-nl-in-textarea-makes-double-tags)

This is how I'm showing the data(works fine, no br tags):

```
<p>{!! nl2br(e($index->paragraphOne)) !!}</p>
```

And this is how I'm trying to edit the data (and adds one br tag after saving every time):

```
<div class="fieldBox">
  <div>
    <label name="paragraphOne" class="label">Paragraaf 1:</label>
    <textarea class="textInput" name="paragraphOne" rows="10">{{ $index->paragraphOne }}</textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: show some code?

Comment: _Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlspecialchars function to prevent XSS attacks._ [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#displaying-data)